# How to result Unable to open 'strtol_l.c' when debugging in VSCode

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I'm trying to debug a simple Cpp program that reads an input file and make a graph from it. However, when trying to debug on VSCode, this error pops up:

```
Unable to open 'strtol_l.c': Unable to read file '/build/glibc-ZN95T4/glibc-2.31/stdlib/strtol_l.c' (Error: Unable to resolve non-existing file '/build/glibc-ZN95T4/glibc-2.31/stdlib/strtol_l.c').
```

Here is my program:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    unordered_map<int, vector<int>> graph;

    ifstream input("input1.txt");
    string row;
    while (getline(input,row)) {   >>> where the error is
        istringstream iss(row);
        int node1, node2;
        if (iss >> node1 >> node2) {
            graph[node1].push_back(node2);
            graph[node2].push_back(node1);
        }
    }
    input.close();
}
```

here is my launch.json:

```
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "(gdb) Launch",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/a.out",
            "args": ["input1.txt"],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

A picture of the error:

[image: error]

Any hint?

Comment: Don't care of this file, this is from glibc sources. What error is happening?

Comment: @S.M. Hi, I added the image of the error when I press F5 to enter debug mode

Comment: This is not an error. Don't perform step into library functions while debugging. Use step over.

Comment: If you have to debug into library functions, you've probably already lost. Even if you proved you're right and the library's wrong, what are you going to do other than change compilers?

Comment: Surprised that no answer has been provided for this. I am getting this error for a specific run, the code is segfaulting, with this error. I dont want to debug into that library function, I just want to know where this error is happening.